# this scope in Arrow Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, scope, this

Per my understanding, arrow function should have same same scope with the context where it was created in.
Like below one return:" This is the box number green big ", which I understand.

```js
let box6={
    color:'green',
    position:1,
    font:'big',
    clickMe:function(){
    return ()=>{
    let str='This is the box number '+this.color+' '+ this.font;
    console.log(str)
    }  }
    }
```

but in React Class, the handleClick arrow function is defined in class LoggingButton, it suppose to have same scope with it, but in the console, it returns: this is LoggingButton, I thought it should return global scope or whatever scope one level higher than LoggingButton.
why is this happening?
Thank you very much!!!

```js
class LoggingButton extends Component {
  handleClick=()=>{
    console.log('this is :', this)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You might be confused by the `handleClick = …` syntax. That's actually happening in the constructor.

Comment: If `handleClick` was a regular function the scope of `this` would be within `handleClick`. "One level higher" is `LoggingButton`.

Answer (score -4):

It is pretty simple.

`()=>{}` is the same as `function(){}.bind(this)`. And this in your case is `LoggingButton`.

Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: This is wrong. Arrow functions don't bind `this` at all

Comment: Then say what it does. You are saying I am wrong, without stating your own point of view. This is nasty.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/5647260 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: I saw this. But did you know that result is the same if you bind this or apply the arrow function?